# java cannot resolve unicode '\x00a0'

Tags: java, c#, unicode

I have a code that contain `\x00a0` and other characters with `\x`. When I compile this code with C# there is no problem and code works fine but when I switch that code to java there is a compile error illegal escape character. How can I fix this issue.

Java code with escape \  : (i dont want this)

```
IRANSYSTEM="\\x00a4\\x00a5\\x00a6\\x00a8\\x00a7\\x00a9\\x00ac\\x00ab\\x00ae\\x00ad\\x00af";
```

C# code : (work fine)

```
IRANSYSTEM="\x00a4\x00a5\x00a6\x00a8\x00a7\x00a9\x00ac\x00ab\x00ae\x00ad\x00af";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct unicode escape is in java \u{code}

So

```
IRANSYSTEM="\u00a4\u00a5\u00a6\u00a8\u00a7\u00a9\u00ac\u00ab\u00ae\u00ad\u00af";
```